# What's the difference when building .whl files between Windows and Macosx/Linux?

Tags: python, python-poetry, python-wheel

In a repo using Poetry, I've got a local package and a consumer package. The consumer package references the local package with the following pyproject.toml file dependency declaration :

`my_local_package = { path = "./packages/my_local_package-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl", develop = false }`

For my local package building, I've got a bash file that will run `poetry build --format wheel` and then copy the generated .whl file in the "packages" folder of my consumer package. Then, I use `poetry lock` in my consumer package.

This is where there is a problem. My lock file contains the following about the local package :

```
name = "my_local_package"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "A small local package"
optional = false
python-versions = ">=3.8,<4.0"
files = [
    {file = "my_local_package-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl", hash = "sha256:84ed5e2bb8f89090d3026ab3bbb5feccb3019fc5b5449ae35263e7526c837ac4"},
]

[package.source]
type = "file"
url = "packages/my_local_package-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl"
```

The computer I'm using is on Windows, but my CI/CD pipeline is on Ubuntu, and when my bash file is executed, the resulting sha256 in the lock file is different. Therefore, my pipeline crashes when using `poetry install`. I would like to fix that to have the same sha256 for both Windows and Linux environments.

I've checked the following :

- the difference does not come from line endings
- as a .whl file is nothing more than a zip file, I've unzipped it and checked its content. It does not contain any timestamp or things that would dynamically change, and the content of the files is the same on Windows and on a Mac.

Can you help me ? Thank you !

Comment: That looks like a question better addressed towards Poetry directly: https://github.com/orgs/python-poetry/discussions

Comment: @sinoroc I raised an issue on the Poetry repo, but the contributors told me that it wasn't a problem coming from Poetry, as it is normal for Poetry to have different hashes for different files. So my problem is the fact that for the same code, the wheel is different on Windows and on MacOS/Linux.

Comment: Link to discussion on Poetry repo?

Comment: Hello @sinoroc, here is the link to the issue, they closed it as it is not a problem coming from Poetry's side : https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/8777

Comment: From what I understand it is expected behavior. Poetry does not claim to ensure this kind of reproducibility. Not sure what StackOverflow can help you with.